# SQL query optimization for subqueries

Tags: sql-server, subquery, query-optimization

I am trying to speed up a stored procedure, and have the following subqueries:

```
    SELECT
    ...
        ISNULL((SELECT Table1.Order WHERE Table2.STATUS <> 'R'),0) AS 'Order',
        ISNULL((SELECT Table1.Order WHERE Table2.STATUS = 'R'),0) AS 'Reject',
    ...
FROM Table1
LEFT JOIN
Table2
ON Table1.KEY=Table2.KEY
```

Is there a way to more efficiently write the above?

I was thinking an IF statement or something, but not quite sure how to write it.

I'm asking this because I read that it's good to minimize subqueries to improve performance.

Comment: Is that valid syntax?  Where is the FROM in the subqueries?

Comment: Please provide the full and valid query.

Comment: Why are you selecting this as two separate columns?

Comment: *"...I read that it's good to minimize subqueries to improve performance."* You're hoping that a change will help. Hope doesn't scale well. Learn to read the [execution plan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191194.aspx) instead.

Comment: Try a CASE statement. It will at least just give you one column instead of two. I can't speak to how much faster it will be, but you can test it on your system to see.

Comment: They aren't really subqueries. They only access column values from the current row. I'd think of those as being more like expressions.

Comment: @Esoteric Screen Name, two separate columns because there are two separate values to be displayed on report.

Comment: @MartinSmith maybe that's the intention, but as written (with invalid syntax), it's ambiguous at best.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - The syntax is valid though once all the reserved words used as column names are escaped. [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d935d/1)

Comment: @MartinSmith oh gross. Now how do we all unlearn that.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - I hadn't set up a test and looked at the plan until now. The plan for the `CASE` version definitely looks much less convoluted though not sure how much practical difference there would be between the two.

Comment: @MartinSmith I don't necessarily mean for performance reasons. Just looking at that syntax makes me queasy.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - Agreed!

Comment: Sorry, some of those column names were only hypothetical column names...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use CASE WHEN:

```
SELECT 
       /* ... */
       [Order] = CASE
                   WHEN t2.STATUS <> 'R' THEN t1.[Order]
                   ELSE 0
                 END,
       Reject = CASE
                  WHEN t2.STATUS = 'R' THEN t1.[Order]
                  ELSE 0
                END
       /* ... */                
FROM   Table1 t1
       LEFT JOIN Table2 t2
         ON t1.[KEY] = t2.[KEY]
```

Comment: +1 but please don't use `'single quotes'` for aliases - certain forms of this are deprecated and it makes them look an awful lot like string literals. `[square brackets]` are much preferred.

Comment: @Mike - Thanks, this was what I was looking for!...and thanks to all for your input.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using oracle "UNION" equivalent for SQL Server. I have worked on Oracle 10g and you can use like,

```
SELECT Table1.Order 
FROM Table1, Table2 
WHERE Table2.STATUS <> 'R' and Table1.id=Table2.id

UNION or UNION ALL

SELECT Table1.Order 
FROM Table1, Table2 
WHERE Table2.STATUS = 'R' and Table1.id=Table2.id
```

I am not sure whether this helped you or not...!! Anyways...